# how to read template tags as a variable?

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I am have made a template tag which converts string to list.Now I want to iterate for loop over that.for which i need to make the template tag readable as a variable.

this is my **template tag**:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_list(string):
    try:
        list_out = eval(string)
        return list_out
    except:
        return ""
```

and by following method i am calling it
**HTML Code:**

```html
<tr>
    <td>{% get_list object.approvals_pending %}</td>
</tr>
```

kindly anyone tell me how to read template tags as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is detailed in the [documentation on passing template variables to tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag), but there is a bigger issue with your code.

I suspect what you have is `"[a,b,c]"` as a variable and you want to iterate over this in your template; which is why you are doing `eval("[a,b,c]")` to convert it to a list.

Stop doing this, please.

Instead **in your view** you need to properly evaluate the variable, for which you can use the json library:

```
>>> import json
>>> i = '[1,2,3]'
>>> type(i)
<type 'str'>
>>> z = json.loads(i)
>>> type(z)
<type 'list'>
>>> z[0]
1
```

Comment: I agree with the sentiment of not using eval, yet you should provide more evidence on why the poster should not use such function, eval.

Comment: @vz0 Ned Batchelder explained it better than I could [at his blog](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html); and there is there is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) which goes into detail as well.